# About Ethereum password

Tags: wallets, myetherwallet, ico, password, passphrase

I joined Ethereum 's ICO in 2014. But I forgot my password. I have a keystore file but I do not know my password...

So I am thinking of brute force attack on my wallet.

Please tell me the password rules at Ethereum 's ICO. Number of digits, uppercase lowercase, alphameric characters, symbolic character etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this article here for more information. However, it's not guaranteed that you'll be able to recover your password. https://support.mycrypto.com/best-of/ethereum-encryption-bkp-presale-files.html

Comment: Please put the relevant parts of that article here.  Answers consisting just of links aren't particularly helpful and are likely to be deleted.